# docker images are not showing in console but showing in docker hub (allow permission by someone)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am pretty new in docker, The thing is this i have created an account to the [**DockerHub**](https://hub.docker.com/), then someone give me the permission to his/her private repository, i have also configure docker on my local Machine **Ubuntu**.

The docker images are showing on the [**DockerHub**](https://hub.docker.com/), as i am login through the shell also, but whenever i am try to list those images on my local machine not show any of them. i don't know at which point i am wrong. or what important point i am missing

[image: Docker hub private repository image]

---

```
docker image ls or docker image ls -a
```

[image: local machine]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing private images is not supported directly from the command line according to [this thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-private-registry-how-to-list-all-images/21136) which is a little old but still no native support for your case and that's why you will notice that there are custom projects like [this](https://github.com/BradleyA/Search-docker-registry-v2-script.1.0), the project mentioned in the following [comment](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-private-registry-how-to-list-all-images/21136/8) which can help you achieve what you need.

Comment: one more thing, can we can pull these private images from local ?

Comment: yes you can, private images can be pulled directly as long as you have permission to do it. you can open the image page on the dockerhub and you will found the command on the right side. if you didn't logged in - in case of private registry - it will ask you to login.

Comment: have you load these images from python script ever ?

Comment: no but you can use https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html this will help you to do it